# Define a trait with FnOnce, but no return type

Tags: rust

I'd like to define a trait like so (to avoid repetition later):

```
trait Callback: FnOnce() + Send {}
```

However, the compiler demands that I define Output from FnOnce:

> error: the value of the associated type `Output` (from the trait
>   `core::ops::FnOnce`) must be specified [E0191]

I tried to default the value, but it warns that this is unstable.

```
type Output = ();
```

> error: associated type defaults are unstable

What can I define Output as to indicate "No return"? The normal function call syntax simply omits it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix this by being explicit about the return type:

```
trait Callback: FnOnce() -> () + Send {}
```

I'm honestly not sure if this is a bug or not.